# Inline bind(this) for React <Button>

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have code drawing `<table>` in/with React.JS as below:

```
      {data.length > 0 && (
        <tbody>
          {data.map(
            ({ name, activationDate, lastUsage, token, status }) => {
              return (
                <tr key={`${name}${token}`}>
                  <td>{name}</td>
                  <td>{activationDate}</td>
                  <td>{lastUsage}</td>
                  <td>{token}</td>
                  <td>{status}</td>
                  <td>
                    <Button
                      {...css({
                        color: '#337ab7',
                        backgroundColor: 'inherit',
                        border: 'none',
                        padding: '0 12px'
                      })}
                      onClick={(e) => {
                        console.log('click event:', e)
                        this.setState({
                          showDialog: true,
                          selectedDevice: name
                        })
                      }}
                    >
                      <Glyphicon glyph="remove" />
                    </Button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              )
            }
          )}
        </tbody>
      )}
```

I need to know to which row the click button belongs. Tried adding `.bind(this)` before `</tbody>` as:

```
  )}.bind(this)
</tbody>
```

Got `validateDOMNesting(...): Text nodes cannot appear as a child of <tbody>.`

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Can't you just keep track of them in the state?

Answer (score 0):

You are using arrow functions. You don't have to or even can bind arrow functions, as they always inherit the enclosing context.

More info [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).